# Process utf-8 data from MySQL in C++ and give result back

Tags: c++, mysql, utf-8

I just simply want to know - how to get **MySQL results to C++ in string** (or another similar "string" datatype) in a way that would **not deform data saved in utf8_unicode_ci**.

After C++ process, app should **write results back** (to another table) into the database where argument is encoded in utf8_unicode_ci as well.

I read somewhere that using *wide char* is not recommended by Unicode consortium, but my problem is still that a second argument for mysql_query() is string which is not wide enough.

I've already tried some "utf8 string" solutions, but unsuccessfully. I also tried to save data in common string and than write it into the database in the same way (byte after byte), but it doesn't work properly at all... (see my code below)

DATABASE:

save_text: text = ěščřžýáíé

AFTER PROCESS: save_newtext: text = ?š??žýáíé

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mysql.h>
#include <string>

#define ... // server conection

using namespace std;

MYSQL *connection, mysql;
MYSQL_RES *result;
MYSQL_ROW row;
int query_state;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
  mysql_init(&mysql);   
  mysql_real_connect(&mysql,CTH_SERVER,CTH_USER,CTH_PASSWORD,CTH_DB_IN,0,0,0));

  mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8");
  mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8");

  mysql_query(connection, "SELECT text FROM save_text WHERE id = 23");

  result = mysql_store_result(connection);
  if ((row = mysql_fetch_row(result)) != NULL) {    
        string sql;
        sql = "INSERT INTO save_newtext (text) VALUES ('";
        sql += row[0];
        sql += "')";

        mysql_query(connection, sql.c_str());
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It would help if you provided some code that you have already tried, so we can try to diagnose the issue.

Comment: What is your specific problem? You can store UTF-8 in string all you want, read and write to/from files without any problems.

Comment: @Polynomial Okay, my code is here...

Comment: @themel I know, but it is not transferring to database properly... I don't know why. I'm really desperate, unsolvable problem... :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [MySQL Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-options.html)

> mysql_options() should be called after mysql_init() and before
>   mysql_connect() or mysql_real_connect().

So your code should be

```
  mysql_init(&mysql);    
  mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME, "utf8"); 
  mysql_options(&mysql, MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND, "SET NAMES utf8"); 

  mysql_real_connect(&mysql,CTH_SERVER,CTH_USER,CTH_PASSWORD,CTH_DB_IN,0,0,0));
```